# extract raw output files(without extension) from video ffmpeg

Tags: linux, opencv, ffmpeg

ffmpeg -i timer.mp4 -r 1 output_%01d.png

this extract frames in png format every sec,I want raw format(rather than images i need to extract without extension).
need to extract frames without extension from video.

do you know command to extract frames without extension(ie ffmpeg -i timer.mp4 -r 1 output_%01d ,but this gives error)

Comment: Individual packets from a coded stream aren't usually playable. What's the goal?

Comment: rather than images i need to extract without extension

Answer (score 1):

The extension of a file doesn't really determine the format of its contents - that is just a Windows-ism.

You say you want *"raw"* output but that could mean *"raw RGB"*, or *"raw YUV"* or *"raw MJPG frames"*, so I assume you want RGB888 data. You can get 1 frame per second for 5s like this:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -t 5 -r 1 -pix_fmt rgb24 q-%d.raw
```

Personally though, I would go for PPM which is exactly the same but with an additional 3 lines at the top telling you whether binary or ASCII, the width and height and whether 8 or 16-bit:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -t 5 -r 1 q-%d.ppm
```

You can process these files exactly the same as raw, but you can also view them as images with `feh`, **Photoshop**, **GIMP** etc, which I think is a good benefit. Here are the first 3 lines from a 1280x720 video:

```
P6
1280 720
255
```

The remainder of the file is just RGB888 in binary.